# Nominal GDP versus PPP in comparing military spending of different countries?

Tags: gdp, exchange-rates, purchasing-power-partity

Military spending as percentage of GDP is the most used measure of the economic capability of a certain country/military. But Some countries like India for example, have a huge difference between their nominal and PPP GDP (2 billion vs 7.7 billion). So which number is more meaningful to express the economic capability of a certain military ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One argument for using the exchange rate:

> Market exchange rates are determined by the supply and demand of
>   currencies used in international transactions. However, the prices of
>   many goods and services on domestic markets are determined in partial
>   or complete isolation from the rest of the world. Therefore, the MERs
>   do not always accurately reflect differences in price levels between
>   countries.
>
> An alternative is to use purchasing power parity (PPP) conversion
>   factors (or PPP exchange rates). The PPP dollar rate of a country's
>   currency is defined by the World Bank as 'the number of units of a
>   country's currency required to buy the same amount of goods and
>   services in the domestic market as a U.S. dollar would buy in the
>   United States'. >1  The only PPP rates available for all countries are
>   GDP- based basket of goods and services that are major components of
>   the gross domestic product. Such GDP-based PPP rates are designed to
>   control for differences in price levels and thus to provide a measure
>   of the real purchasing power of the GDP of each country.
>
> Using GDP-based PPP rates instead of MERs for currency conversion
>   results in much higher output and expenditure figures for many
>   developing and transition countries since they have relatively low
>   prices for non-traded goods and services—thus giving the currency
>   higher purchasing power. A unit of local currency therefore has
>   greater purchasing power within a developing country (which is better
>   reflected by using PPP rates) than it has internationally (which is
>   what is reflected by using MERs). For those such developing and
>   transition countries for whom data was available for 2008, the median
>   increase in military expenditure figures from using PPP rates instead
>   of MERs was around a factor of 2. Three-quarters of these countries
>   would see their relative figures increase by at least two-thirds.
>   Meanwhile, using PPP rates would cause the GDP and military
>   expenditure figures of most 'developed' countries to fall relative to
>   the USA, by a median rate of 17 per cent—reflecting the low value of
>   the US dollar at market exchange rates in 2008. **However, the
>   reliability of such PPP rates is lower than for MERs, since PPP rates
>   are statistical estimates, calculated on the basis of collected price
>   data for a basket of goods and services for benchmark years.** Between
>   benchmark years, the PPP rates are extrapolated forward using ratios
>   of prices indexes, either GDP deflators or consumer price indexes.
>   Like all statistical estimates they are subject to a margin of error.
>
> **Furthermore, GDP-based PPP rates are of limited relevance for the
>   conversion of military expenditure data into US dollars. Such PPP
>   rates are designed to reflect the purchasing power for goods and
>   services that are representative of spending patterns in each country,
>   that is, primarily for civilian goods and services. Military
>   expenditure is used to purchase a number of goods and services which
>   are not typical of national consumption patterns.** For example, the
>   price of conscripts can be assumed to be lower than the price of a
>   typical basket of goods and services, while the prices of advanced
>   weapon systems and of their maintenance and repair services can be
>   assumed to be much higher. The extent to which this data reflects the
>   amount of military goods and services that the military budget can buy
>   is not known. Due to these uncertainties, SIPRI uses market exchange
>   rates to convert military expenditure data into US dollars, despite
>   their limitations.

[Stockholm International Peace Research Institute: Monitoring Military Expenditures](http://www.sipri.org/research/armaments/milex/measuring-military-expenditures)

But wages are a big part of military costs and those are not paid with PPP GDP but rather domestic GDP. [MEASURING HARD POWER: CHINA’S ECONOMIC GROWTH AND MILITARY CAPACITY](http://MEASURING%20HARD%20POWER:%20CHINA%E2%80%99S%20ECONOMICGROWTH%20AND%20MILITARY%20CAPACITY%20economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/nominal-gdp-versus-ppp-in-comparing-military-spending-of-different-countries) says that both methods have merits but at least in China, both methods understate military capacity.

> **The most appropriate way to compare real military capacity across
>   countries is to deflate each country’s actual, or potential, military
>   spending by the price of real military services in each country.
>   Unfortunately military price indices do not exist for most countries.**
>   The aim of this paper, therefore, is to develop a simple method for
>   computing a relative military price index, that deflates nominal
>   spending into units of real military services, using readily
>   accessible data. The ratio of two countries’ military price indices
>   then gives an exchange rate that provides an index of relative real
>   military capacity across countries. **We use this military exchange rate
>   to compare the level and growth of China’s real military capacity
>   relative to the USA**. 4 We obtain two key results. First we find that
>   **the value of the RMB, in terms of its ability to purchase real
>   military services, is greater than both its market exchange rate value
>   and its PPP value.** This suggests that conventional estimates of GDP
>   understate China’s real military capacity, but also that PPP exchange
>   rate comparisons are much closer to the actual value than market
>   exchange rate comparisons. This is mainly because of the very low cost
>   of labor in China relative to the USA. 
>   ...
>
> If we wish to infer
>   country’s miliary capacity based on the size of its economy, however,
>   standard PPP indices also pose a problem insofar as they reflect the
>   relative price of an average basket of goods produced in the economy
>   and this average price index may differ substantially from the price
>   of military services. Thus C**rane et al (2005) argue that, while
>   military services have large personnel costs, a substantial share of
>   military equipment purchased by developing-country militaries is
>   imported or incorporates com- ponents that are manufactured from
>   materials and parts sold at world market prices, such as electronics,
>   diesel engines, or aircraft frames. Thus they suggest that, for some
>   purposes, GDP measured at market exchange rates may give a more
>   realistic picture of changes in military capacity** (Crane et al 2005,
>   pp.16-17). Similarly, the two principle military statistical
>   abstracts, The Military Balance published by The International
>   Institute for Strategic Studies (IISS), and the Stockholm Interna-
>   tional Peace Research Institute’s (SIPRI) Yearbook report relative
>   military spending and relative GDP in terms of $US converted at market
>   exchange rates and also at PPP ex- change rates. IISS (2012) notes
>   that market exchange rates are likely to understate the true level of
>   economic resources allocated towards defence since food material and
>   hous- ing costs will be lower in China, but remain noncommittal in
>   recommending a preferred price index. 8 Thus they often report a
>   weighted average of PPP and market exchange rates when discussing
>   China’s real military capacity relative to the USA.